# Does Spring DataSourceTransactionManager support REQUIRES_NEW?

Tags: java, spring, spring-transactions

I test “spring transaction propagation” like this:

```
fun A(){
  funB()
}
ClassA.fun A:REQUIRED 
ClassB.fun B:REQUIRES_NEW
transactionManager: DataSourceTransactionManager
```

And it runs OK,that is:DataSourceTransactionManager support transaction propagation "REQUIRES_NEW".

but the description of org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager(spring-tx-4.3.14.RELEASE.JAR) shows :

```
 * <p><b>Transaction suspension (REQUIRES_NEW, NOT_SUPPORTED) is just available with a
 * JTA TransactionManager being registered.</b> Common TransactionManager locations are
 * autodetected by JtaTransactionManager, provided that the "autodetectTransactionManager"
 * flag is set to "true" (which it is by default).
```

Who can tell me which one is right?

Comment: Hi Denny, welcome to Stackoverflow. Can you give us more background information on what you are trying to do, what problems you've encountered and what you have attempted? It is not clear from "I test it, ...."

Comment: If you are refering to the line "(REQUIRES_NEW, NOT_SUPPORTED)", those are both different means of transaction propagation. Both suspend the current transaction, if any, but NOT_SUPPORTED runs outside a transaction, and REQUIRES_NEW creates a new transaction.

Comment: @Dmich yes,I know "transaction propagation",but I just want to confirm the description is wrong.

Comment: @Francis OK,Thanks,I edited it.

Comment: Yes it does. It is your code that is doing the wrong thing. Internal method calls don't pass through the transactional proxy. So basically the `REQUIRES_NEW` is ignored.

Comment: @M.Deinum You mean the source description of JtaTransactionManager is wrong?And DataSourceTransactionManager actually support transaction propagation "REQUIRES_NEW".  Mine test runs OK:funA and funB is not in the same java class .

Comment: Then please modify your question to reflect that, as currently it looks as it is in the same class. Also the fact that something is document in `JtaTransactionManager` doesn't mean other tx managers don't support it. Your test already proves that. There is nothing in `DataSourceTransactionManager` that tells you that `REQUIRES_NEW` isn't supported.

Comment: @M.Deinum ok,I modifed it.  but the source description is :"Transaction suspension (REQUIRES_NEW, NOT_SUPPORTED) is just available with a JTA TransactionManager being registered." which use “just available"...

Comment: Which applies to the `JtaTransactionManager` NOT the `DatasourceTransactionManager`.

Comment: @M.Deinum Okay,it misleads me.Thanks a lot !